# Playing video consisting of multiple large parts online?

Tags: video, stream, media-source

For various reasons I am only able to upload mp4 video files of 500MB each at most.
Some videos that I need to display in my online video player are rather large (3-5GB).

I know of adaptive streaming but in my case the files are pre-uploaded on different servers (and are in large chunks) so that is not gonna be possible.

Therefore, my question is:

Does any video player exist that can play a multiple video files "as one" video?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5's Media Source Extension mechanism (MSE) allows you build a player which can add video data dynamically as it is downloaded - this is how HTML5 adaptive bit rate players generally work.

MSE essentially replaces the 'src' file of the video element with a reference to a Javascript function. In the function you can dynamically fill in the video element's source buffer, so you can add new chunks of the video as they are available.

For you this is likely not going to help as each video will still have header information associated with it and hence will effectively be seen as a new video anyway.

One way to do what you want are to have a player which supports playlists and can play one after another without a gap - this requires there player to preload the next video in the playlist to avoid the startup delay.

Another approach which will work with a standard player is to have two separate players on your page - this approach is often used for pre, mid and post roll adverts, which are often from a different source than the main video itself.

You simply play the first video and when you are near the end preload and then pause the second video but keep the player hidden. At the point where the first video ends, you hide the first plater and show and start the second player. Its a little involved, but it does work.